# Evaluate $\int_0^1{\frac{y}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm a little rusty with my integrals, how may I evaluate the following:

$$
\int_0^1{\frac{y}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy}
$$

I've tried:

$$
\int_0^1{\frac{y}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy} = \int_0^1{\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}} dy} 
$$

Make the substitution z = 1-y

$$
= \int_0^1{\sqrt{\frac{1-z}{z}} dz} = \int_0^1{\sqrt{\frac{1}{z} - 1} dz}
$$

Which seems simpler but I have not managed to evaluate it. All help appreciated (just a few pointers would be appreciated just as much as the full solution).

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Solution following Ng Hong Wai suggestion:

At 
$$
\int_0^1{\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}} dy} 
$$

We make the substitution $y = sin^2(\theta)$, so $dy = 2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)d\theta$. This results in:

$$
 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{2 sin^2(\theta)d\theta} = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{[1-cos(2\theta)]d\theta} = [x-\frac{1}{2}sin(2\theta)]_0^\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Solution according to M. Strochyk's suggestion:

$$
\int_0^1{\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}} dy} = 2 \int_0^\infty{\frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}du}
$$

By decomposing into partial fractions this becomes:

$$
2 \int_0^\infty{\frac{1}{1+u^2}du} - 2 \int_0^\infty{\frac{1}{(1+u^2)^2}du}
$$

The first term integrates directly to $arctan(u)$ while the second can be evaluated by making the substitution $u=tan(x)$ and then applying the double-angle formula for cosine. The result is (unsurprisingly):

$$
 2[arctan[u]]_0^\infty -[x + \frac{1}{2}sin(2x)]_0^\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: Complete the square?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At $$\int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}}}dy,$$ you can use substitution $y=sin^2\theta$

Comment: Am I correct in saying that I could not use this substitution if my limits of integration went outside of [0, 1]?

Comment: @AmosJoshua : yes

Answer (score 6):

By using [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$\int_0^1{\frac{y}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy}=B(3/2,1/2)=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/2+1/2)}=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/2)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $u=\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{1-y}}.$ Then 
$$\dfrac{y}{1-y}=\dfrac{y-1+1}{1-y}=-1+\dfrac{1}{1-y}=u^2, \\
( {0}< {y} <{1} \Leftrightarrow {0}< {u}<{+\infty}),\\
\dfrac{1}{1-y}=1+u^2, \\
1-y=\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}, \\
y=1-\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}, \\
dy=\dfrac{2u}{(1+u^2)^2}\, du,
$$
so 
$$\int\limits_0^1{\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{1-y}} dy}=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}{\dfrac{2u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}}\, du=2\int\limits_0^{+\infty}{\dfrac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}}\, du$$
Last integral can be calculated by decomposition into partial fractions.

Comment: A little more work but thank you for this suggestion as well, I was just as rusty with partial fractions